# Gson to Model containing several return types for one key

Tags: java, json, gson

i just had a problem converting the JSON from Phillips Hue Lights (Response) to a Model. Since it may contain several "unknown" keys in success and/or may contain just a String for success i had to write/use a TypeAdapter and a deserializer aswell. This works but im pretty sure there is a better way to solve this.

Dummy JSONS:

```
[{"success":{"/config/name":"My bridge"}}]
```

and

```
[{
    "success":{"id": "3"}
}]
```

and

```
[
{"success":{ "address": "/groups/1/action/on", "value": true}},
{"success":{ "address": "/groups/1/action/effect", "value":"colorloop"}},
{"success":{ "address": "/groups/1/action/hue", "value":6000}}
]
```

And the JSON with just a String

```
[{
    "success": "/config/whitelist/1234567890 deleted."
}]
```

It may also contain "error" but this isnt the problem. Since the object in address is unknown i use a Adapter from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627869/simple-way-to-strip-outer-array-of-responses-in-gson which works fine as long as its an Object. Since it may also contain a String i had to create a JsonDeserializer which validates if its a JSONObject and if not, it sets another variable in the Model with the message. It works, but i always have to revalidate if the message or success it set.

This is my JSONDeserializer

```
public class HueResponseDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<HueResponse> {
    private final String TAG = HueResponseDeserializer.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public HueResponse deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        HueResponse response = new HueResponse();
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        if (jsonObject.get("success").isJsonObject()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("success").entrySet()) {
                response.setSuccess(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                    put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }});
            }
        } else {
            response.setSuccessMessage(jsonObject.get("success").getAsString());
        }

        if (jsonObject.has("error") && jsonObject.get("error").isJsonObject()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("error").entrySet()) {
                response.setError(context.deserialize(entry.getValue(), HueResponse.Error.class));
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

And my Model

```
public class HueResponse {

    private Map<String, Object> success;
    private Error error;
    private String successMessage;

    public String getSuccessMessage() {
        return successMessage;
    }

    public void setSuccessMessage(String successMessage) {
        this.successMessage = successMessage;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public Error getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Map<String, Object> success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public void setError(Error error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public static class Error {
        private int type;
        private String address;
        private String description;

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Type: " + this.type
                    + " Address: " + this.address
                    + " Description: " + this.description;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont have any influence since this is how Phillips Hue respond. https://developers.meethue.com/documentation/configuration-api#71_create_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Iterating through an `entrySet()`

If what you really want is to put all the JSON objects into a `success` map, rather than overwriting each of them with every iteration, there's a way to stream it:

```
Map<String, Object> map = object.entrySet().stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, 
                                            entry -> (Object) entry.getValue()));
result.setSuccess(map);
```

In any case, a more fluent implementation of `HashMap<>() {{ ... }}` is to use [`Collections.singletonMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap-K-V-):

```
object.entrySet().forEach(entry -> { 
    Map<String, Object> map = Collections.singletonMap(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); 
    // ...
});
```

#### Modeling

You can consider have a more domain-based modeling of the successful results, instead of a simple `Map<String, Object>` in your `HueResponse`. For example, consider a `Group` of `Action` objects that have a state consisting of `enabled` (aka `on`), `effect` and `hue`? That seems to adhere closer to the results, giving you a more meaningful application.

Comment: Thank you, but does it really solve the issue? If i see that correctly its just to use Lambdas which generates one more function (if not two) -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WALV33rWye4&t=1600s. The issue/problem is that the return value of success may or may not a JSONObject. It may also just a String or anything else.

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold the first part addresses the double-brace initialization usage, which is unnecessary. The second is a suggestion on a richer model than just a mapping of `JsonElement` objects in your `HueResponse` class.